# RAD8 not recognizing WPS7 state after starting

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I am working in **RAD8** at the moment and try to build portlets for **WPS7**. I installed both of it on my **Windows 7** development machine.

When I start the server from the *servers* view, everything happens like expected: a console pops up (2 consoles in fact, one for the WAS and one for the WPS), the server displays its status as **[Starting, Synchronized]** and I wait for 2 or 3 minutes while the console is scrolling with WPS messages.

But when I get to this lines it gets weird: (not only for the language...)

```
[28.12.11 15:40:49:373 CET] 00000000 RMIConnectorC A   ADMC0026I: Der RMI-Connector ist an Port 10035 verfügbar.
[28.12.11 15:40:49:373 CET] 00000005 LeaseAlarm    I   SCHD0133I: Der Scheduler WPSTaskScheduler (wps/Scheduler) hat die Zugangsberechtigung erhalten und führt alle Tasks in diesem Anwendungsserver aus.
[28.12.11 15:40:49:389 CET] 00000000 JMXConnectors I   ADMC0058I: Der JMX-JSR160RMI-Connector ist an Port 10035 verfügbar.
[28.12.11 15:40:49:436 CET] 00000000 WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Der Server WebSphere_Portal ist für e-business bereit.
```

Apparently the server is started, because it is telling me so with `WSVR0001I` and I can browse the portal homepage. But RAD is still displaying **[Starting, Synchronized]** and will run into the timeout after a while. After the timeout dialog popped up, the server status is **[Stopped]** although I can still browse the portal and get console messages.

I already checked the SOAP and RMI ports, and they are correctly set to RMI=10035 and SOAP=10025.

Any hints?

*update* This seems related https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255957

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually realized I had changed the eclipse.ini for some phonegap/mobile development.  When I reverted the file back to the original one, it worked.

Comment: Hm, I can't remember modifying the INI file. But I didn't have that under version control, so I can't revert back easily. I think I'll reinstall RAD soon and hope that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your WebSphere Portal instance is secured, and you didn't correctly populate the security settings in the RAD server configuration pertaining to your WP7 instance.

Another reason might be using the RMI connector. Using the RMI connector is known to cause such problems. You didn't mention which connector you're actually using; if you haven't already done so, use the SOAP connector.